# What is the best way to organize a feed of different types in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema

Let's say I have three types of data: `A`'s, `B`'s, and `C`'s. A looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "4ccdfb68-ce18-4361-bd90-e61f1fcf8d2b",
    "created_at": "2016-11-27 02:24:12.889637+00",
    "author": "7d16389b-2d66-4c59-bb6a-87992a60d112",
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": "zab",
    "cat": "dog"
}
```

B looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "4ccdfb68-ce18-4361-bd90-e61f1fcf8d2b",
    "created_at": "2016-11-27 02:24:12.889637+00",
    "author": "7d16389b-2d66-4c59-bb6a-87992a60d112",
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": "zab",
    "nak": "kan"
}
```

And C looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "4ccdfb68-ce18-4361-bd90-e61f1fcf8d2b",
    "created_at": "2016-11-27 02:24:12.889637+00",
    "author": "7d16389b-2d66-4c59-bb6a-87992a60d112",
    "baz": "zab",
    "cat": "dog"
}
```

There are (smallish) variations in their fields, but they have some consistent fields ("metadata" so to speak). Each of these represents their own data type--B is not A with different fields. However, at a later point I need to combine the most recent of all three into a "feed":

```
[{
    "id": "4ccdfb68-ce18-4361-bd90-e61f1fcf8d2b",
    "type": "A",
},
{
    "id": "4ccdfb68-ce18-4361-bd90-e61f1fcf8d2b",
    "type": "B",
},
{
    "id": "4ccdfb68-ce18-4361-bd90-e61f1fcf8d2b",
    "type": "C",
}]
```

Should I create a single table representing all three with their shared fields and a JSONB field, or should they have their own tables and do a union query on them? To be clear, the feed will only have shared fields. I also need this to be forward-compatible--I know for a fact future types will have an ID, a created_at field, and an author, but beyond that it's fair game.

Thanks! Feel free to ask for details.

**Edit:** Ah, yes, I forgot to mention that I also want to (at some future point) make indexes on a field (if the row has it) so that I can search for all rows where "foo" == "bar". If a row doesn't have foo, that shouldn't break this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've chosen to go with a single table for several reasons:

1. JSONB is perfect for this situation--I have a few columns I want on everything, but the rest is dynamic.
2. I can still make indices on the JSONB data (specific to the type of data).
3. I can order the feed descending by a column in one index and have all of the keys be in the same table.
4. I can combine separate, related tables (comments).
5. It makes more sense overall.

Here is the table description:

```
                                          Table "public.feed"
   Column   |           Type           |                           Modifiers                           
------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id         | uuid                     | primary key unique not null
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
 created_by | uuid                     | not null default '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid
 data       | jsonb                    | 
Indexes:
    "feed_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "feed_created_at_index" btree (created_at DESC)
    "feed_data_index" btree (data)
    "text_index" gin (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, data ->> 'text'::text))
```

Comment: I forgot to include a `type` column. It exists :)